# Target of URL doesn't exist: 'import 'package:velocity_x/velocity_x.dart';

Tags: flutter, dependencies, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

When trying to import velocityX 1.0 , it gives Error Like this
**"Target of URL doesn't exist: 'import 'package:velocity_x/velocity_x.dart';**

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

```
  dependencies:
    velocity_x: ^1.0.0
```

Then run

`$ flutter pub get`

Import should work now.

Comment: I Have done this all things still, this gives an error.  then i upgrade flutter version 1.0.0 to 1.22.3 then this error solved

Comment: Ok. Great it was your flutter version issue then